# Simple Imgur API

Tags: java, api

I slowly made an Imgur client and everything works but I have few questions about how to make classes more OOP and cleaner.

1. Is that correct to make `generateToken` static when it is private?
2. Is calling the method from the constructor an anti-pattern?

   ```
   public class ImgurClient extends Imgur {

       public ImgurClient(String client_id, String client_secret) {
           super(client_id, client_secret);
           generateToken();
       }

        private static void generateToken(){
            System.out.println("Enter into link, accept application and paste here full redirect url to get credentials");
            System.out.println(ImgurURLs.getAuthorizeUrlWithClientID());
            ImgurAuthentication imgurAuthentication = new ImgurAuthentication(); //todo metody statyczne? moze na gore?
            imgurAuthentication.getURLFromUserAndGenerateTokenFromImgurOauth();
        }

        @Override
        public void getAccountBase() {

        }

        @Override
        void getAccountImages() {

        }
   }
   ```

This is the class where I parse redirect URL with tokens:

3. Should every methodbe static here?
4. I know calling two methods from one method is incorrect, but how should I make it better?
5. Extract methods are pretty similar. How should I make it better?

   ```
   public class ImgurAuthentication {

       private final Pattern accessTokenPattern = Pattern.compile("access_token=([^&]*)");
       private final Pattern refreshTokenPattern = Pattern.compile("refresh_token=([^&]*)");
       private final Pattern expiresInPattern = Pattern.compile("expires_in=(\\d+)");
       private final Pattern accountIdPattern = Pattern.compile("account_id=(\\d+)");

       private Matcher matcher;
       private String url = getUrlFromUser();


       public void getURLFromUserAndGenerateTokenFromImgurOauth(){
           getUrlFromUser();
           extractTokensValueFromURL();
       }

       private String getUrlFromUser(){
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           return scanner.nextLine();
       }

       private void extractTokensValueFromURL(){
           try{
               extractAccessToken();
               extractRefreshToken();
               extractExpiresIn();
               extractAccountId();
           }catch (IllegalStateException ex){
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect authorization url", ex);
           }
       }

       private void extractAccessToken(){
           matcher = accessTokenPattern.matcher(url);
           matcher.find();
           AccountCredentials.TOKEN=matcher.group(1);
       }

       private void extractRefreshToken(){
           matcher = refreshTokenPattern.matcher(url);
           matcher.find();
           AccountCredentials.REFRESH_TOKEN=matcher.group(1);
       }

       private void extractExpiresIn(){
           matcher = expiresInPattern.matcher(url);
       matcher.find();
           AccountCredentials.EXPIRES_IN = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
       }

       private void extractAccountId(){
           matcher = accountIdPattern.matcher(url);
           matcher.find();
           AccountCredentials.ACCOUNT_ID = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
       }
   }
   ```

This is my `const` class where I keep everything about the user:

6. I know keeping `const` in an interface is an anti-pattern. How about that way?

   ```
   public final class AccountCredentials {

       private AccountCredentials(){}

       public static String CLIENT_ID = "";
       public static String CLIENT_SECRET = "";
       public static String TOKEN = "";
       public static String REFRESH_TOKEN = "";
       public static long EXPIRES_IN = -1;
       public static long ACCOUNT_ID=-1;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AccountCredentials` class should be treated as an object and not a set of constants:

```
public final class AccountCredentials {
    private final String id;
    private final String secret;
    private final String token;
    private final String refreshToken;
    private final long expiry;
    private final long accountID;

    public AccountCredentials(String id, String secret, String token, String refreshToken,
            long expiry, long accountID){
        this.id = id;
        this.secret = secret;
        this.token = token;
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        this.expiry = expiry;
        this.accountID = accountID;
    }

    /* getters omitted for brevity */
}
```

This trickles down to the `ImgurAuthentication` class, which now has the "goal" of returning an `AccountCredentials` object.  With a little refactoring:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ImgurAuthentication {

    private final Pattern accessTokenPattern = Pattern.compile("access_token=([^&]*)");
    private final Pattern refreshTokenPattern = Pattern.compile("refresh_token=([^&]*)");
    private final Pattern expiresInPattern = Pattern.compile("expires_in=(\\d+)");
    private final Pattern accountIdPattern = Pattern.compile("account_id=(\\d+)");

    private final String url;

    public ImgurAuthentication(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public AccountCredentials generateCredentials(String id, String secret){
        try{
            return new AccountCredentials(id, secret, getAccessToken(),
                    getRefreshToken(), getExpiry(), getAccountID());
        }catch (IllegalStateException ex){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect authorization url", ex);
        }
    }

    private String getAccessToken(){
        Matcher matcher = accessTokenPattern.matcher(url);
        matcher.find();
        return matcher.group(1);
    }

    private String getRefreshToken(){
        Matcher matcher = refreshTokenPattern.matcher(url);
        matcher.find();
        return matcher.group(1);
    }

    private long getExpiry(){
        Matcher matcher = expiresInPattern.matcher(url);
        matcher.find();
        return Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
    }

    private long getAccountID(){
        Matcher matcher = accountIdPattern.matcher(url);
        matcher.find();
        return Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

I would recommend not catching `IllegalStateException`, since that can be indicative of bigger things and should be passed up the chain.  Instead, maybe check the result of `matcher.find()` and return `null` or `throw new IllegalArgumentException();` if false?

That just leaves the `ImgurClient` class, which keeps an `AccountCredentials` field for itself:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ImgurClient extends Imgur {

    private final AccountCredentials credentials;

    public ImgurClient(String client_id, String client_secret) {
        super(client_id, client_secret);
        credentials = generateToken();
    }

    private AccountCredentials generateToken(){
        System.out.println("Enter into link, accept application and paste here full redirect url to get credentials");
        System.out.println(ImgurURLs.getAuthorizeUrlWithClientID(this.getClientID()));
        ImgurAuthentication imgurAuthentication = new ImgurAuthentication(readURL());
        return imgurAuthentication.generateCredentials(this.getClientID(), this.getClientSecret());
    }

    @Override
    public void getAccountBase() {

    }

    @Override
    void getAccountImages() {

    }

    private static String readURL(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

A quick note for future reference: favor shorter method names.  `getURLFromUserAndGenerateTokenFromImgurOauth()` is a mouthful!

Comment: You could further abstract away duplicate code in the `ImgurAuthentication` class by making a method like `getFirstMatch(Pattern pattern)` and replacing `getAccessToken()` with `getFirstMatch(accessTokenPattern)` and the other methods with their respective equivalents.

Comment: @jodekpotasu I realized that after I posted.  See the comment above.  Better yet, here's a quick implementation: https://hastebin.com/avokobihij.java